# add search user functionality to my search page with Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add search user functionality to my search page, using firebase. I am only testing with just the display Name but each time I search at least 3 letter of the display name I do not get the username displayed. I tried searching with the full name and still do not get the username displayed.
I don't know what is wrong.
This is the code:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
 import 'package:social_appify/model/user.dart';
 import 'package:social_appify/pages/home.dart';
 import 'package:social_appify/widgets/progress.dart';
 
 class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   const SearchScreen({super.key});
 
   @override
   State<SearchScreen> createState() => _SearchScreenState();
 }
 
 class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
   TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
    Future<QuerySnapshot>? searchResultsFuture;
 
    handleSearch(String query) {
      Future<QuerySnapshot> users =
      usersRef.where("displayName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query).get();
 
      setState(() {
        searchResultsFuture = users;
      });
   }
 
   clearSearch(){
      searchController.clear();
   }
 
   AppBar buildSearchField() {
     return AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       title: TextFormField(
         controller: searchController,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
           hintText: "Search for a user...",
           prefixIcon: const Icon(
             Icons.account_box,
             size: 28.0,
           ),
           suffixIcon: IconButton(
             onPressed: clearSearch,
             icon: const Icon(
               Icons.clear,
             ),
           ),
         ),
         onFieldSubmitted: handleSearch,
       ),
     );
   }
 
   buildNoContent() {
     final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
     return Center(
       child: ListView(
         shrinkWrap: true,
         children: [
           SvgPicture.asset(
             'assets/images/search.svg',
             height: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 300.0 : 200.0,
           ),
           const Text(
             "Find Users",
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,
             style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.white,
               fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
               fontSize: 60.0,
             ),
           )
         ],
       ),
     );
   }
 
   buildSearchResults(){
      return FutureBuilder(future: searchResultsFuture, builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<Text> searchResults = [];
        for (var element in snapshot.data!.docs) {
         User user = User.fromDocument(element);
         searchResults.add(Text(user.username));
        }
        return ListView(
          children: searchResults,
        );
      });
   }
 
 
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
       appBar: buildSearchField(),
       body: searchResultsFuture == null ? buildNoContent() : buildSearchResults(),
     );
   }
 }
 
 
 
 class UserResult extends StatelessWidget {
   const UserResult({super.key});
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return const Placeholder();
   }
 }
```

[image: this is the blank screen result I get]

Comment: Does it work with 2 letters? Firebase orders strings lexicographically, which means it compares string values character by character, from left to right, and it is also **case sensitive**

Comment: Oh I see the problem... when I enter any 3 letter of the display name, it gives me the username but when I type the username nothing occurs... the display name is Isaac and the usernam is Reed. when I enter Isa only it gives me Reed